# Is it safe in practice to cast an array of pointer to an array of reference_wrapper?

Tags: c++

I have code manipulating an array of pointers. For the sake of this question, let’s pretend it’s something like `int**` but it could be anything from `std::array<int*, N>`, `std::vector<int*>`or `std::span<int*>`.

The legacy API is something like

```
void f(int** x);
```

And I want to replace it with

```
void f(std::reference_wrapper<int>* x);
```

To facilitate the migration, I still want allow the old API. But I do not want this to come with a copy of the input array.

As far as I understand, `int**` and `std::reference_wrapper<int>*` have the exact same memory layout. My strategy is hence to have this adapter:

```
// Legacy API assuming all pointers are non nullptr
void f(int** x) {
  int**& y = x; // To make gcc -Wall happy
  f(reinterpret_cast<std::reference_wrapper<int>*&>(y));
}
```

This is raising some safety and behavior consistency concerns:

1. Does this work as intended?
2. Are there real life implementations of `std::reference_wrapper` that would not be compatible with this?
3. Is there any aliasing issue for some pedantic compiler?
4. Would it be an issue in practice with any of the containers I mentioned at the beginning?
5. Is there a better way to write this adapter?

Comment: Provided "a reference is not a pointer" dichotomy, I don't think such a casting is safe here

Comment: @TheDreamsWind But they have the same memory layout (a memory address). So interpreting a non null pointer as a reference is well defined

Comment: A `std::reference_wrapper<int>` is a class type, which may have different layout (representation in memory) from an `int *`.   As such, the conversion from `std::reference_wrapper<int> **` to an `int **` (or vice versa) is unsafe - and behaviour will be undefined on dereferencing.

Comment: To make my question clear. I know this is "unsafe" in theory. I’m concerned about practical issues given actual implementations of the standard. For instance, I cannot think of any reasonable implementation of `std::reference_wrapper` that would break this code

Comment: `I’m concerned about practical issues given actual implementations of the standard`, and the standard says nothing about `std::reference_wrapper` and a pointer layout compatibility, it doesn't requires it, so assuming this will hold everywhere makes such an implementation unsafe because it's beyond what the standard requires. (and even if different implementation of `std::reference_wrapper` is unreasonable, it still would be perfectly legal)

Comment: @GuillaumeGris Suppose the optimizer sees an `std::reference_wrapper<int>` that's never used as a reference, only as an `int` (possibly after other optimizations have inlined/eliminated any reference uses). It might reasonably assume it can optimize the *whole* variable to an `int`, not noticing that there actually *is* another reference to it, but its declared type is `int*`. Even if the implementation has the same *representation* for both, if you and the optimizer are making different assumptions about what the rules are, then the optimizer is going to destroy your code.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Your explanation misses the point. An object is used either as `std::reference_wrapper<int>` or as `int*`, but not as plain `int`.

Comment: @j6t You're missing the point that, as soon as behaviour is undefined according to the standard, implementations are permitted (and modern optimisers often do, in practice) to make various assumptions - and reorganise code accordingly.   All it needs is a mismatch between assumptions made by the programmer and assumptions made by (implementers of) the compiler/optimiser, and behaviour of the program is not what the programmer expects.  As soon as someone makes an assumption about what is a "reasonable implementation" in the presence of undefined behaviour, they open that door.

Comment: @Peter I agree on all accounts what you say. Silvio says "a `reference_wrapper<int>` that is never used as reference, only as `int`". However, OP's code never intends to use a `reference_wrapper<int>` as `int`, it intends to use it as `int*`. It's still undefined behavior (no doubt about that), but the details of the Silvio's conclusions what a compiler can make from it may be different.

Comment: I’ve been experimenting with this with gcc, clang and VS for a few days now. It seems to work just fine in practice. If anyone finds a situation where this does not work as intended, don’t hesitate to propose it as an answer

Comment: I’ve been checking the strict aliasing rule and this seems fine with usual implementations of `reference_wrapper<T>` which have a pointer to T as data member. Assuming such an implentation and applying aliasing rules, (most notably 10.3 and 10.6), there should not be any optimizer issue here, even with heavy inlining (this matches my multiple experiments with compiler explorer)